# Delphi ZEOSlib: read from a table and write it to another database

Tags: mysql, database, delphi, zeos

Is it possible to read a table from a database with delphi zeoslib and write it back to another server?

I think it, to read the table and write back the resultset, but i don't know how, is it possible?

I thought for the following:
I made an zquery: `Select * from table1`, with `zconnection1` and I want to insert the results back to another database, to `zconnection2`.

I use `mysql` databases.

Comment: Of course it's possible; that probably doesn't help much, but then you didn't ask anything except "Is it possible" twice. If you want help here, you need to be specific about your question, provide some information we can use to help you, and at least show some effort to figure it out yourself. Do you have code that at least reads from the table first? Do you have any information about the other database we can use? Please [edit] your question, so we can try and help you find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Edited for more details.

Comment: I mean, read a table from db1 and write it into another db which has a same table.

Comment: So? make `insert` query for the 2nd connection, read the source zQuery row by row and set `insert`'s parameters the values of those rows, then execute the `Insert` and `.Next` the source query until it would be `.EOF`

Comment: google "ZeosLib DataPump" shows http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yHMYRf6QBD0J:www.kumanov.com/docs/database/Zeos/+&cd=7&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru&lr=lang_en%7Clang_ru&client=opera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if MySQL (or Zeos) supports cross-server queries; the `MySQL documentation` should answer that portion. Whether Zeos allows that to get through to the DBMS is also a question I can't answer; one of the drawbacks to using open-source products is that they usually lack documentation that would tell you these things.

One way that I know for sure would work (although it would be a little slow for very large tables) is to do it row by row:

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM MyDataOnServer1';
  while not ZQuery1.Eof do
  begin
    ZTable1.Append;
    for i := 0 to ZQuery1.FieldCount - 1 do
      ZTable1.Fields[i].Value := ZQuery1.Fields[i].Value;
  end;
  ZTable1.Post;
end;
```

The other two possiible alternatives that come to mind (neither of which I know whether MySQL or Zeos supports) are

- Export the table from server1 as a backup, and restore it to server2
- If `SELECT...INTO` is supported, you could select into a temporary disk file on server1, and then do an `INSERT FROM` that temporary disk table into server2

Comment: Not merely Zeos - just a mere bridge passing query text here and there - the underlying RDBMS servers (and they can be different) should support that as well

Comment: @Arioch'The: It's certainly true that the underlying DBMS affects this, but often data access libraries limit functionality so as to provide that flexible support between DBMS systems. I have no clue if Zeos would support this even if the underlying DBMS does. The old BDE used to provide it's own implementation of SQL that masked platform differences (but also put limitations on what you could do in that SQL). I edited to clarify that, though, and to rephrase it somewhat. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Yes, BDE was weird beast. But for what i remember LocalSQL was only used on non-SQL data sources or on cross-server queries (downgrading those servers to non-SQL rows generators). When you used SQLinks to, for example, Interbase, you used server features that did not existed in LocalSQL like ID Generators

Comment: Yes, that's probably true. I stopped using the BDE in Delphi 1, and never used it again except to answer questions about it on the old Compuserve groups and in the Borland forums. I stopped installing it at all several years ago when that became an option. :-)

Comment: Modified solution, that work for me:

procedure TForm1.copy2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,j: Integer;
begin
  ZQtavoli.ExecSQL;
  Zqtavoli.Open;
  Zthelyi.Edit;
  for j:=0 to ZQtavoli.RecordCount do
  begin
    Zqtavoli.Next;
    ZThelyi.Append;
    for i := 0 to ZQtavoli.FieldCount - 1 do
      ZThelyi.Fields[i].Value := ZQtavoli.Fields[i].Value;
  end;
  ZThelyi.Post;
end;